# Multi connection option for Openvpn management interface

Tags: openvpn

Is there any option for multi connection to openvpn management interface? 
I can make one connection at same time. I need more.

Regards, Hakan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, [the documentation](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html) explicitly says:

> Currently,
>   the OpenVPN daemon can at most support a single management client
>   any one time.